# Running Appium test on a MAC with c#

Tags: c#, appium, ios, hybrid

Im little bit good at c# and not at JAVA , So is there any way to write Appium scripts on a MAC using c# ?

My target is to make some automation scripts to test an android and iOS build which developed using ionic framework.AKA Hybrid framework.

I went thru some tutorials on executing Appium/Selenium tests on a MAC and everything was written in JAVA which im not familiar very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can make it working with [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) or the new [Visual Studio for Mac](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/) (which is in Beta).

Here is a blog about Selenium with C# on a Mac with Xamarin: http://testerstories.com/2015/11/c-and-selenium-on-xamarin/

Microsoft is supporting C# in Mac with its new .Net Core: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet

I would suspect that if Selenium works Appium would also work, but I think you are on your own. Certainly when you run into trouble, you will be one of the only trying and doing this.

Java looks a lot like C#, so maybe the switch is not so hard as you think it is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471448/tips-for-moving-from-c-sharp-to-java

Comment: Damn,http://testerstories.com/2015/11/c-and-selenium-on-xamarin/ is not working